# How can I use IValueConverter to convert a font in bold

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, ivalueconverter

**Hi I am trying to convert the font style of a row in a DataGrid depending on the type selected by a combobox. I'm not getting and is returning the following error:**

> "Error 18 'System.Windows.Documents.Bold' does not contain a
>   constructor que takes 1 arguments

**This is my class:**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace enLoja.enLoja_Web.Helpers
{
    public class GrupoBoldConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var weight = new Bold(FontWeights.Normal);
            switch (int.Parse(value.ToString()))
            {
                case 2:
                    weight = new Bold(FontWeights.Bold);
                    break;
                default:
                    weight = new Bold(FontWeights.Normal);
                    break;
            }
            return weight;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is how I decorate my datagrid:**

```
<sdk:Page.Resources>
    <Helpers:GrupoBoldConverter x:Key="BoldConverter" />
</sdk:Page.Resources>
```

...

```
<sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding SINTETICO, Converter={StaticResource BoldConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**I know that the syntax error is. My problem is that I can not use the correct option.
I thank anyone who can help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FontWeight` property expects a [FontWeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontweight.aspx) not a `Bold`. Return just the `FontWeight` from your converter.

Comment: I tried this way: 

var weight = new FontWeight(FontWeights.Normal);

And still getting the same error.